# Having more than one form in one page. How to validate it then? CakePHP

Tags: php, forms, validation, cakephp

```
<?=$this->Form->input('username');?>                  
<?=$this->Form->input('email');?>
```

I want to use Form helper. But let's say I have two forms in one page. How I would validate the other one if each of them has two different actions?

Of course I could use `$this->ModelName->validationErrors` and use `foreach` to display errors, but I think it's bad practise.

Comment: Simply, you can't without ajax. What specifically are you trying to validate? Sending a form to an action will not submit the other form, so what's the point in validating it?

Comment: You are sending two distinct form at the same time ? or two fields on the same form ?

Comment: There are two forms. Add category and add tags

Comment: Again, why would you want to validate something you aren't going to save? If you're saving a tag, why does what the user entered in a category field matter if you're not saving it on that request?

Answer (score 0):

You can clearly not validate two forms on one page without using javascript based validaton rules or AJAX. And by the way: relying just on JS validation without doing it server side would be silly.

Make it one form and then you can validate both in the model and the controller will set the errors to view. The way the forms are thought to work in the HTML makes it not possible to submit 2 forms at the same time that are one one page - for obvious and logical reasons. And that's not related to CakePHP but the HTML standard.

This page covers all you need http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation/validating-data-from-the-controller.html